# Running JavaFX Applications: JFXPanel vs Application.launch

Tags: java, javafx, osgi, javafx-8

I am currently doing a large `JavaFX` application using `Apache Felix` and having doubts on what to do in the startup process. I did some experiments and found 2 possible ways in starting `JavaFX` in an `OSGi` environment.

**First approach** is use `JFXPanel()` by doing some kind of `JavaFX bootstrap`. I am not embedding `Swing Applications` this is to initialize the `JavaFX Thread`.

```
public class JavaFXEnvironment {
    public static void start(){
        return new JFXPanel();
    }
}
```

I would just call `JavaFXEnvironment.start();` then use my `JavaFX` application's start method in the `Activator Bundle`.

```
Platform.runlater(() -> {
    new SampleApplication.start();
});
```

**Second approach** is to use `Application.start()` method.

```
public class SampleApplication extends Application {
     public void start(Stage stage) {
         ... /* Do JavaFX stuffs in here */
     }       
}
```

Then call `Application.launch(...)` in the `Activator Bundle`.

What would be the implications when using one of the approach?

Are there any disadvantages when using JFXPanel even when I am not embedding `Swing Applications`?

Comment: Use `Application.launch(...)`, because it is the standard way to do things.

Comment: I thought of that also but if there are no significant differences on both approach I would use the first one as I find it easy to manage in the osgi environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use Application.launch, eg. start it in a Declarative Service or an Activator. You will have to start a new Thread, since the call is blocking.

Using JFXPanel would add Swing to the mix and probably also the Swing Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

Please note that I've released some Early Access versions of [Drombler FX](http://wiki.drombler.org/DromblerFX), a new modular Application Framework for JavaFX based on OSGi (Apache Felix) and Maven (POM-first).

You can read more about Drombler FX here: http://puces-blog.blogspot.ch/search/label/Drombler

There's a [Getting Started](http://wiki.drombler.org/GettingStarted) page which explains how to create, build and run a Drombler FX sample application with a few simple steps.

Comment: The first approach works, calling `new JFXPanel()` initializes the `JavaFX` thread but I didn't know that there will be unused threads running in the background. Using `Application.start` has some issues like manually setting the `classLoader`.

Comment: @Arjay I didn't have any ClassLoader issues in this area so far. So again: Drombler FX might help you to solve those issues as it provides OSGi/ JavaFX integration out-of-the-box.

Comment: I took a look with `DromblerFX` and it looks fine, it is the second time around you suggest the framework but it is too late for me or for the code base to migrate to `DromblerFX`. It would be a great opportunity to test your framework for a large code base but not now :)